# Can't enter settings menus on 'Google Home' purchased in USA

Tags: android, internationalization, actions-on-google, mobile-application, google-home

I'm ***Canadian*** and was recently gifted a **[Google Home](https://store.google.com/product/google_home)**, from an ***American***.

It works great with standard tasks like music, reminders, etc, and I've been playing with customization [ITTT](https://ifttt.com/discover), which so far works fine, including features like SMS and callings.

The problem is that **I can't access certain settings** in the [Android app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.chromecast.app) — tapping them does nothing.  For example, **I can't :**

- `Set up voice match` (although it recognizes my voice)
- `Manage news sources` (although it plays local news when commanded)
- `Setup Shopping List` (although the feature works fine)

I can't help but think this is related to the fact that this unit wasn't made for my country (although they are available here too).

[image: img]

**Does anyone know if there's a way around this** either programmatically, or maybe a setting I haven't seen, or some other workaround?

---

**Related:**

- AndroidCentral : [Top 8 things to know about Google Home in Canada](https://www.androidcentral.com/google-home-canada)
- Wikipedia: [Google Home](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Home)

Comment: New enough equipment that it's tough to find an answer... but I did get closer to an answer today:  Several pages from Google and their partners mistakenly state that at minimum, Android 4.4 is required.  Turns out they were wrong - Android 5.0 is required and they are working to update all the pages. However the good news for me is that Samsung put out a 5.0 upgrade that apparently will work on my old Galaxy handset - even though they announced long ago there will be no further updates to it.  I'll know for sure in a day .

Comment: (I was assured that the Canada/USA difference is irrelevant.)  Thus, I suppose this new information makes this "not a programming question" however I will leave it for now because others will likely be looking for programmatic solutions to the same problem i had.